# Python Add-in- Message Box to display area of selected polygons

Tags: python, area, python-addin

I am looking to create a Python AddIn which calculates the area of selected polygons.  I would like to be able to select the features, click a button on the toolbar, and a Message box displays the sum area.  Is this possible without writing the area to the table?  I hope that makes sense.  I am very new to Python.

Comment: Please include the tag for the software you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

> pythonaddins.MessageBox()

See links below for examples:

[Getting results from your Python Add-in buttons](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/12/11/getting-results-from-your-python-add-in-buttons/)

[The pythonaddins module](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//014p00000021000000)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ArcGIS, here is an example Python Addin that calculates areas:

```
class CalculateArea(object):
    """Implementation for Test_addin.calculateArea (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        # Set mxd to current and data frame to active
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
        activeDF = mxd.activeView
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, activeDF)[0]
        calcArea = 0
        # Create a list of all layers in the active data frame and iterate through each layer
        layerList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df) 
        for layer in layerList:
            # Create a Describe object for each layer and check that it supports FIDSet
            descLayer = arcpy.Describe(layer)
            if hasattr(descLayer, "FIDSet"):
                # If the FIDSet is not empty, there must be a selection on the layer
                if descLayer.FIDSet != '':
                    # Use da.SearchCursor to access the SHAPE@AREA token for each selected feature
                    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, ["SHAPE@AREA"]) as cursor:
                        # Iterate through each selected feature in the layer and sum the areas
                        for row in cursor:
                            calcArea += row[0]
        # Display the final sum in a message box
        pythonaddins.MessageBox(calcArea, "Calculated Area", 0)
```

A couple of things to note:

1. FIDSet is a property of a Describe object that can be used to check for a selection. You could also check for polygons, but it isn't really necessary - selected lines and points will just add 0 to your calculated area.
2. This code will sum the areas of all selected features in all layers in an active data frame - the code can be simplified by targeting a specific layer if that is all you require.